# Cannot get Identity Server to launch the default home page

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, identityserver4

I am learning from code written on APS.Net Core v1 on setting up an identity server, and I am using v2, including the QuickStart code for Identity Server.
I have the default Index page set up the Home Controller that comes with the Quickstart code.
I find this code launches the console but not the webpage.

```
   public class Startup
    {
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var url =
                @"C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\SIR\SIR.OAUTH\SIR_SSL_Certificate.pfx";
            services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddSigningCredential(new X509Certificate2(url, "xxxxxxxx"))
                .AddTestUsers(InMemoryConfiguration.Users().ToList())
                .AddInMemoryClients(InMemoryConfiguration.Clients())
                .AddInMemoryApiResources(InMemoryConfiguration.ApiResources());
            services.AddMvc();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole();
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseIdentityServer();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
        }
    }
```

The line `app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();` is executed but the Index page is not launched. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: This is the Console Log as requested in the Comment;
[image]

Comment: Could you share us a screen shot about your Console Windows? I assume your launch your app from project.exe instead of IIS Express. For IIS Express, it will launch the index automatically. For `project.exe`, you need to enter the url in web browser by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I really hope this works because I came across the same issue earlier this year.
I had to put my `services.addMVC/configure.addMVC` at the top of services and the the bottom of the method calls. Here is an example:

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            //mvc  //-------------------------->HERE!!!!!!!!!!
            services.AddMvc();

            //add indentity server
            services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
                .AddTestUsers(Config.GetUsers())//<---gets from static method in Config class
                .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())//<-method in Config class
                .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources()) //PASS In api res list frm cnfg
                .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients());//--Config getClients()





        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env,ILoggerFactory lf)
        {
            //loggerfactory
            lf.AddDebug();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            //call iden4
            app.UseIdentityServer();
            app.UseAuthentication();// just added 1-22 18
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
            app.UseMvc();  //---------------------------------------->HERE!!!
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Mohamoud. Unfortunately your solution did not work. I am at a stage where I will try anything, but it is hard to see that putting app.UseMvc() would make a difference. If you look at the code behind the UseMvcWithDefualtRoute() method, you will see it executes app.UseMvc() anyway, albeit with a route assigned.

Comment: Here is an old repo of mine of a class I took. It took me 5 days to get it running due to 2.0+ issues. here it is : `https://github.com/fasecity/IdentityServer4`

Comment: Thank you for that Mohammed. I looked at your project and I saw in your project properties that you had set it to IIS Express and ticked the launch browser checkbox. This worked, so thank you for that.